# LevelDB random read -- why is official benchmark so good?

Tags: c++, database, storage, benchmarking, leveldb

According to this [official benchmark](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/benchmark.html), it performs 129,000 ops/sec on random read. But as I know, random read needs at least ONE random access to disk (cache has no help with random read because the whole database is much larger than cache), and one random access disk needs about 10ms for disk seeking. That should make random read slower than 100 ops/sec.

I've done a simple test with 100,000,000 MD5 strings on my slow machine. random write performs about 50,000 ops/sec (which is not far from the official benchmark) and random read performs about 20 ops/sec.

The question is: Why do leveldb's official benchmark get such a high result? I don't see special optimizations on the benchmark code, and the benchmark doesn't use something like an SSD disk.

Answer (score 1):

The official benchmark results you linked to are for a dataset so small that it fit entirely in the RAM of their test machine. I.e., the filesystem cache held all of the data, even if the LevelDB cache did not.

Here's a test showing how HyperLevelDB performed when the dataset was 5x and 50x larger than RAM. (HyperLevelDB is a fork of LevelDB developed by the HyperDex folk, with improved write throughput compared to the original. It's all a lot slower than `LMDB` though.)
http://symas.com/mdb/hyperdex/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you run the read test immediately after the write test. After the write test, leveldb may perform compaction, which cause heavy disk IO and slow down reads. So you should wait awhile after your write test. With 100,000,000 MD5 strings writes, I think you should wait minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ricon East 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vo88IdglU_8) presentation on throughput has some nice graphs and describes the problems with huge throughput and how they fixed it in Riak.